# Magento - Some product's options section do not load

Tags: magento

I have an issue on some product pages in our magento store.  The child html will not load into the template for some product.

In catalog/product/view.phtml the following will not load for some products.

getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>

Sometimes it gets corrected when we just save the product again in the admin, and it gets corrected.  However, this does not always work.

We have not made any changes to the layout/catalog.xml file

Products were imported and not added manually.  This issue only seemed to happen on one import.

Comment: screenshots: https://docs.google.com/a/seekmomentum.com/file/d/0Bxz5n6GONspzbFJGOTFyWjlSTW8/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: screenshot (works fine) same layout nothing different except a different product: https://docs.google.com/a/seekmomentum.com/file/d/0Bxz5n6GONspzV05MNzQyQ3JmT0U/edit?usp=drivesdk